# Removing 3rd party extensions

Tags: macos, 3rd-party

I found that I have a lot of unknown 3rd party plugins installed in my Mac.

[image]

I thought they are Safari extension, but Extensions popup menu in Safari do not show these extensions.

[image]

How to remove these unknown extensions? I don't remember I install some of the extensions (especially those Chinese extensions); how come they ended up in my Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're built-into the OS. Just leave them switched off & ignore.

[image]

See [how to delete extensions Youku, Tudou, etc...](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6845389?start=0&tstart=0) which pretty much says the same thing. Especially pay attention to anything Linc Davis ever says; he's the closest thing to an actual authority on the Apple forums.