# Third party extension is preventing M1 2020 MBP from booting

Tags: macos, startup, sleep-wake, recovery, kernel-extensions

****MBP 2020 M1,
OS: Big Sur 11.7.9****

My mac started malfunctioning lately: this morning I opened the lid and was greeted by the recovery screen telling me that there was a problem with the computer.

I dismissed the warning and tried to start my mac as usual.

It managed to boot with no issues but right after I prompted my password, it hung:

[image]

It freezes for about 2 minutes and then reboots. Needless to say that this cycle is never ending.

I reinstalled the OS from the recovery screen and and seemed to fix the problem.
After logging in there was a notification saying:

[image]

Also, it gave me quite a lengthy log-file

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe002921ddcc): "busy timeout[0], (60s): 'RootDomainUserClient', 'RootDomainUserClient', 'RootDomainUserClient', 'RootDomainUserClient', 'RootDomainUserClient', 'RootDomainUserClient', 'RootDomainUserClient', 'RootDomainUserClient', 'RootDomainUserClient', 'RootDomainUser"
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 20G1426
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Thu Jul  6 22:12:47 PDT 2023; root:xnu-7195.141.49.702.12~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: 64500501AB4C8A39523312AE79C8C6F4
Kernel UUID: 2955FDA5-5B8C-3F0F-B10C-785F74C833B1
iBoot version: iBoot-6723.140.2
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000020f08000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe0027f0c000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000021a50000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe0028a54000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe0028b20000
mach_absolute_time: 0xb2958b97
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x64f30607 0x0007eacb
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x64f3067e 0x0004732a

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0028c926d0
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0028c93d98
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0028c93d98
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0028c93d98
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0028c93d9c
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0028c93d9c
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0028c93d9c
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0028c93d9c
CORE 0 PVH locks held: None
CORE 1 PVH locks held: None
CORE 2 PVH locks held: None
CORE 3 PVH locks held: None
CORE 4 PVH locks held: None
CORE 5 PVH locks held: None
CORE 6 PVH locks held: None
CORE 7 PVH locks held: None
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0xfffffe0028b99a90, LR=0xfffffe0028b99a88, FP=0xfffffe3fe36a3ee0
CORE 2: PC=0xfffffe0028b99a90, LR=0xfffffe0028b99a88, FP=0xfffffe3fe4fe3ee0
CORE 3: PC=0xfffffe0028b99a90, LR=0xfffffe0028b99a88, FP=0xfffffe3fe36c3ee0
CORE 4: PC=0xfffffe0028b99a90, LR=0xfffffe0028b99a88, FP=0xfffffe3fe4f5bee0
CORE 5: PC=0xfffffe0028b99a90, LR=0xfffffe0028b99a88, FP=0xfffffe3fe35fbee0
CORE 6: PC=0xfffffe0028b99a90, LR=0xfffffe0028b99a88, FP=0xfffffe3fe3ff3ee0
CORE 7: PC=0xfffffe0028b99a90, LR=0xfffffe0028b99a88, FP=0xfffffe3fe3623ee0
Panicked task 0xfffffe16686247d8: 245 pages, 4 threads: pid 309: watchdogd
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe16683e5348, backtrace: 0xfffffe3fe36f3520, tid: 3206
          lr: 0xfffffe0028b6eb4c  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3590
          lr: 0xfffffe0028b6e930  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3600
          lr: 0xfffffe0028c991f4  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3620
          lr: 0xfffffe0028c8a678  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f36d0
          lr: 0xfffffe0028b277e8  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f36e0
          lr: 0xfffffe0028b6e5c0  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3a70
          lr: 0xfffffe0028b6e5c0  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3ae0
          lr: 0xfffffe0029323944  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3b00
          lr: 0xfffffe002921ddcc  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3ba0
          lr: 0xfffffe0028c5ea2c  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3bd0
          lr: 0xfffffe0028b7429c  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3c40
          lr: 0xfffffe0028b4ba98  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3cc0
          lr: 0xfffffe0028b64710  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3d70
          lr: 0xfffffe0028c7f000  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3e40
          lr: 0xfffffe0028c8a6f4  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3ef0
          lr: 0xfffffe0028b277e8  fp: 0xfffffe3fe36f3f00

last started kext at 1587625269: com.apple.filesystems.autofs   3.0 (addr 0xfffffe00289cc000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:

*listing loads of apple's kexts*
```

I thought the problem was gone, closed the lid (it went to sleep), but when I returned home the very same thing happened - the greetings from the recovery screen, inability to log in... Had to do the recover my computer again.

I really don't know what to do. If it really has to do with some sort of kernel extension, how to turn it off then by default?

In addition, when the computer is messed up the touch bar goes flickering for no good reason.

What seems to be the problem and how to troubleshoot and solve it?
I don't want to turn off the sleep mode, so my mac is up all the time.

Comment: First step imho, is to remove ALL 3rd party extensions and see if it boots normally.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251954/removing-3rd-party-extensions

Comment: Can you boot to Safe Boot mode?

Comment: @benwiggy
No, it freezes just the same

Comment: I'd be tempted to erase the Data volume, and then selectively restore from your backup.

Comment: @SolarMike how to do so?
From my research there's no way to manage kernel extensions starting from (or even below) my version of MacOS